# Place things in a specific iteration element in Vue

Tags: html, vue.js, nuxt.js

Let's say I create 20 `div`s using a `v-for`. 
Then let's say I have a lot of data in an array, and each unordered element of this array belongs in one of the 20 `div`s (they have an `index` or something that tells where they belong, but not necessarily all of them).

The simple way to do this would be to iterate over the array on each one of the `v-for` `div`s and check if the `indexes` match and if they do, render them. Something with a `v-if element_index == for_index`. But this is really inefficient because if there's a lot of data and the `v-for` has a lot of iterations, this grows a lot for a simple webpage.

Is there a way to do the opposite of this? So first generate the 20 divs, then run through the data array and one by one insert them where they belong?

Comment: could you share a tried code?

Comment: I haven't really tried because I only know what the non optimal solution to this would be. I actually have no idea if my idea is possible. Maybe I should do it in another way

Answer (score 1):

I would use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a "bucket" object keyed by the grouping indexes.

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each member of the array resulting in a single output value.

**Example**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      dataArray: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    bucket () {
      return this.dataArray.reduce((obj, item) => {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(item.index)) {
          Object.assign(obj, {
            [item.index]: [item]
          })
        } else {
          obj[item.index].push(item)
        }
        return obj
      }, {})
    }
  },
  created() {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      this.addData()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addData() {
      this.dataArray.push({
        index: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3),
        name: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)
      })
    },
    removeData() {
      this.dataArray = this.dataArray.slice(1)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="addData(true)">Add Data</button>
  <button @click="removeData">Remove Data</button>
  <div v-for="key in Object.keys(bucket)" :key="key">
    <h3 style="font-family: monospace">Bucket {{ key }} ({{ bucket[key].length }} items)</h3>
    <p v-for="(item, index) in bucket[key]" :key="item.name" style="font-family: monospace; border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(96,125,139,.1)">{{ index + 1 }}. {{ item.name }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-template-compiler@2.5.17/browser.min.js"></script></script>
```

Comment: Well I have no idea what that does and how it works. But in that approach you can't dynamically add more data for the array, right? Or even dynamically increase the size the div "list"

Comment: You sure can. Computed properties react to changes in the underlying data (ie `this.bigArrayOfData`)

Comment: @Myntekt I've updated the answer to demonstrate Phil's comment.